# ACL allow actions not working in Cakephp 2.x

Tags: cakephp

I have a multi step travelrequest app. Users are directed to the 1st step e.g localhost/intraweb/travel_requests/step/1 up until they get to the last step localhost/intraweb/travel_requests/step/5. Problem that i am having now is only administrators can access the steps and normal users cant. In my case users have an ID = 10 in my groups table

This is how i am using ACL in my UsersController

```
//allow users to do a travel request
public function initDB() {
$group = $this->User->Group;
$group->id = 10;
$this->Acl->allow($group, 'controllers/TravelRequests/step($stepNumber');
}
```

here is my code for my TravelRequestsController

```
public function beforeRender() {
parent::beforeRender();
$params = $this->Session->read('form.params');
$this->Auth->allow('step($stepNumber)');
$this->set('params', $params);
}

public function setup() {
$steps = 5;
$this->Session->write('form.params.steps', $steps);
$this->Session->write('form.params.maxProgress', 0);
$this->redirect(array('action' => 'step', 1));
}

public function step($stepNumber) {
if($this->Session->read('form.params.steps') != 5) {
$this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
}

if (!file_exists(APP.'View'.DS.'TravelRequests'.DS.'step_'.$stepNumber.'.ctp')) {
$this->redirect('/travel_requests/index');
}

$maxAllowed = $this->Session->read('form.params.maxProgress') + 1;
if ($stepNumber > $maxAllowed) {
$this->redirect('/travel_requests/step/'.$maxAllowed);
} else {
$this->Session->write('form.params.currentStep', $stepNumber);
}
}
```

Does some have an idea on what i am missing out in my code?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to allow `$this->Acl->allow($group, 'controllers/TravelRequests/step($stepNumber');` where `step($stepNumber` is not an existing action.

You should use `$this->Acl->allow($group, 'controllers/TravelRequests/step')` instead.